# How can I move these input elements down in relation to their labels?

Tags: css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3YUTM/)

I want to move the input elements down in relation to their labels (only about 3 pixels). The main problem I am having is that making the inputs `display: block;` breaks the whole layout. I need the code text to appear right under the label and input that it is associated with, as it does now.

HTML:

```
<label for="inputSize"><p>Size</p><input id="inputSize" class="char2" type="text"><br><code>font-size: 17px;</code></label>
<label for="inputWeight"><p>Weight</p><input id="inputWeight" class="char3" type="text"><br><code>font-weight: 400;</code></label>
<label for="inputSpacing"><p>Letter-spacing</p><input id="inputSpacing" class="char2" type="text"><br><code>letter-spacing: 0;</code></label>
<label for="inputWSpacing"><p>Word-spacing</p><input id="inputWSpacing" class="char2" type="text"><br><code>word-spacing: 0;</code></label>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
label p {
    background: aqua;
    display: inline-block;
    color: @gray1;
    padding: 1px 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
input {
    font-family: monospace;
    height: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px #b8b8b8;
    border: 0;
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: and you've tried display:inline-block?

Comment: Yes, it functions like inline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `position: relative` you can move an element around relative to where it is supposed to be (in your case with `top: 3px`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/3YUTM/1/

Comment: Just out of curiosity, isn't everything `position: relative;` by default, I mean, I must be wrong, but whats the default?

Comment: No, `position: static` is usually (I think always, in fact) the default